# Bivariate random variable

Tags: probability-distributions

Let x1,x2,x3. Be independent random variables with common pmf P[x=+-1]. Write x3=x1.x2. show that x1, x2,x3 are pairwise independent but not mutually independent

Comment: Please show your work.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

What is $Pr(X_3=1)$?  What is $Pr(X_3=1\mid X_1=1,X_2=1)$?  Are these equal?  What does this imply?